# Replace all spaces between a fullstop and a quotation mark globally in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I want to replace all spaces between a fullstop and a quotation mark globally.

Following is a sample string I have from some user data -

```
John said, "Hello, I hope you are well. "
```

I would like some javascript code that will turn such a sentence into this -

```
John said, "Hello, I hope you are well."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

search for this :

```
(.+I hope you are well\.) (")
```

and replace with :

```
$1$2
```

demo here :

http://regex101.com/r/zT1kB6

Now and example in javascript :

```
var str= 'John said, "Hello, I hope you are well. "\nyes he might "be. " But we cannot rely on that .';
var res = str.replace(/(.+I hope you are well\.) (")/, '$1$2');
console.log(res);
```

here you can see that the space is replaced, but the space after `be. "` is not getting replaced.

Comment: The specific sentence was only sample data - I want something that will do a global replace on all . " 

So from your code.... str.replace(/(\.) (")/, '$1$2');    ????

Comment: use a global modifier like this `/(.+I hope you are well\.) (")/g` and you will get it

Comment: Perfect - thanks. Final code was - 

readText = readText.replace(/(\.)  (")/g, '$1$2');

Comment: @CraigSchwarze but if you wanted this, a normal replace would have worked

Comment: @aelor Just what I'm saying ;-). The answer of does exactly the same without using a REGEX

Comment: @morten.c yes you are right, but the question was a bit misguiding for me :)

Comment: @aelor Yes, you're right, that was the reason why I didn't answer the question that fast like Andy does. My critic was aiming the question more than your answer

Answer (score 4):

Just search for dot-space-quote and [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with dot-quote?

```
str = str.replace('. "', '."', 'g');
```

Comment: +1 since the question doesn't sounds like a REGEX is necessary.

Comment: It's not that specific question. Everything regarding a REGEX would just be guessing ;-).

Comment: it will replace all `. "` with `."` which the OP doesnt want

Comment: That's explicitly what he _does_ want. "[I want to] eliminate the space between the fullstop and the quote".

Comment: @Andy More specific: That's explicitly what he is *saying*, not sure if it's what he *wants*.

Comment: @Andy quoting OP `A global replace on fullstops only won't work, as I want to preserve those spaces in other parts of the text.`

Comment: @aelor **on fullstops** he was saying, not *on fullstops before quotation marks* Which now already turned out in the comments below your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
var string = '"Hello, I hope you are well. "';
var modified = string.replace(/. "/g,'."');
```

Simple bit of regex which will find and replace as many instances of . " as required.